# Is it possible to disable Android firmware update notifications?

Tags: android, notifications, firmware

I have an application running on phones that aren't meant to be touched or interacted with in any way.  I want my application to run correctly 24/7/365.

The only issue I'm having is that every few weeks or so, a notification pops up about updating the firmware on the device.  It doesn't immediately interrupt the app running but after a few days of no one accepting/declining the firmware download, the app crashes.

Is there any way (either programatically or by changing phone settings) to disable these firmware update popups, or to disable automated firmware updating in general?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: This might work for you http://cdmagurus.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-3518.html use at your own risk..

Comment: What about a solution that doesn't require rooting your phone?  Now that my phone is working exactly the way I want it, any update represents a substantial risk to me.  It is getting very annoying getting a message every 12 hours, without the option to disable this intrusion.

Comment: If these devices happen to get their network access via wifi you control, you might be able to filter it to block access to whatever servers are responsible.

Comment: If it's just a matter of intercepting and dismissing the notification, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235776/remove-notification-from-notification-bar-from-other-applications

Answer (score 4):

3 easy steps:
1. Install free System Tuner
2. Go to Startups
3. Select Google Services Framework
4. Uncheck SystemUpdateInstallDialog and SystemUpdateInstallDownloadDialog

IMPORTANT: You need a rooted device to run this app!

Simple and easy way to stop the system update notification...

Source: http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-7-tablet-2012/234006-how-do-i-remove-system-update-notification.html

Answer (score 2):

To avoid confusion with the original question I'll repeat the Bounty-Question by [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376947/alex) first:

> Does anyone know what is the URL of google that we can block in Pi-Hole to make the notification go away?

All HTTP-based messages -- including push notifications -- via Google's Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) backend go through the server-side endpoint `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`, as described in the reference on the [Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref). The client-side endpoint doesn't seem to be publicly documented, however one can suppose that blocking `https://fcm.googleapis.com` should do the job.

Analogously all XMPP-based messages go through the endpoint `fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com`, as documented in the reference on the [Firebase Cloud Messaging XMPP protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref).

*Edit:* [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376947/alex) found another interesting URL, namely `notifications-pa.googleapis.com` (see his comment below).

Comment: thanks, this is the only answer that tries to solve the issue. I don't know if  that is the url that triggers the notif, but I was watching pi-hole like a hawk this week and found this url `notifications-pa.googleapis.com` in a request that was made the same time I got the update popup on the phone. I added both this and your domain to the black-list, I will wait & see if this makes the update bs go away

Comment: @Alex -- `notifications-pa.googleapis.com` sounds interesting. I made a quick search and maybe this pi-hole forum thread from 2021 will interest you : https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/google-2fa-issue/46938

Comment: if blocking it makes 2FA go away without any side effects that's even better :) But I believe 2FA is still optional for now, as I don't remember being asked more than the pw

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible

---

**Settings**

1. Goto "settings"
2. find the "about phone" or "system" entry in settings
3. look ofr the "software update" or "system update" option
4. There should be  a 3dotted menu with "settings", or a direct link to `Download and install updates automatically`.

**turn it off.**

---

**3rd party**

You may also consider (this is what I personally do) installing 3rd party software like [NetGuard](https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard) (for example) and disable internet connection to the system process that checks for updates. If there is no internet connection for the software/app it will not badger you with notifications.

---

**Turn off notifications**

Got to the settings of the app responsible for updates. And turn off all permissions related to notifications.
You won't be badgered with the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

on android in the notification bar you can press the notification long time. than an info button should appear. when you click this button you get the system app, which creates the notification. then in the settings of this app you can block every notification. just block all. maybe you will miss other important notifications, i don't know.