# Can't cancel Notification using NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

This is my service:

```
public class Listener extends NotificationListenerService {
    Context context;

    @Override

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override

    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        String title = extras.getString("android.title");
        String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();

        Log.i("Msg",pack);
        Log.i("Msg",ticker);
        Log.i("Msg",title);
        Log.i("Msg",text);

        Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
        msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
        msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
        msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
        msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);
        Toast.makeText(context, "GOT SOMETHING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 //final String T=  sbn.getKey();

        Listener.this.cancelAllNotifications();
    }

    @Override

    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i("Msg","Notification Removed");
    }
}
```

For testing, I would like to **DISMISS ALL NOTIFICATIONS FROM ANY APP** as soon as they arrive. I have called  `Listener.this.cancelAllNotifications();` inside onNotificationPosted, but it does not work.

What am I doing wrong ? I am testing this on android version 5.0.2.

P.S.

I HAVE added the permissions along with the intent filter, as android mentions.

```
<service android:name=".NotificationListener"
          android:label="@string/service_name"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
     </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the 'Notification Access' is active (checked) for the app implementing your **NotificationListenerService**.

It can be verified in 'Settings' menu. It is at either of the addresses depending upon the Android version. For Android 5.0, it should be at:
Settings -> Sound & notification -> Notification Access

Or else, you may find at:
Settings -> Security -> Notification Access

Try enabling it for your app and then try to clear the notifications.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to enable that choice programmatically rather than fire an intent to open settings page and let the user do that? 

By the way, should be marked as an answer!

Comment: Nope, it requires user action to enable it, just like enabling Dev Admin for APP

Answer (score 0):

For how to let user enable their Notification Access,

You can show a Popup ("Please enable Notification Access"), and when user clicks "OK", it will redirect user to the settings page, to enable the Notification Access settings.

```
private static final String ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS = "android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS";

private void openNotificationAccess() {
    startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));
}
```