# Turn notifications on/off for other apps through my app

Tags: android, notifications

How can we turn off/on the notifications for other apps through an app of our own? What special permissions or code setup is required?

App for reference

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.araneaapps.android.apps.notificationdisable

Comment: It should be kind of hack/workaround, because using standard methods you can't off other apps notifications. You can only listen them using `NotificationListenerService` which is available starting API>=18

Comment: You can use the information from following two questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757878/how-to-read-all-the-coming-notifications-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803218/cant-cancel-notification-using-notificationlistenerservice